# How To Read Variable Value Using mdb?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, illumos, omnios

Let's say I set a parameter with the following command, how could I read it back later on?

`mdb -kwe "spa_load_verify_metadata/W 0"`

I am trying to read the [man page](https://illumos.org/man/1/mdb), but I'm only in this OS temporarily and don't understand what it's talking about.

```
The search modifiers are:
       l   Search for the specified 2-byte value.
       L   Search for the specified 4-byte value.
       M   Search for the specified 8-byte value.
```

I would normally expect that value to be in `/sys/modules/zfs/parameters/spa_load_verify_metadata` where I could just `cat` the value, but `/sys` doesn't even exist.

I tried finding the variable using `find`, but it wasn't in the filesystem. I don't understand the concept of where these values are...

I'm actually just trying to read the values of [other parameters that I know to exist](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/wiki/ZFS-on-Linux-Module-Parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, the natural way to export kernel parameters is virtual files in /sys or /proc.  On Solaris and its derivatives, the debugger mdb can be used to read and write values.

```
# mdb -ke "spa_load_verify_metadata::print"
0x1 (B_TRUE)
```

Or as I used to do it:

```
# echo "spa_load_verify_metadata::print" | mdb -k
0x1 (B_TRUE)
```

You can find more information about the symbol with the debugger:

```
# mdb -k
> spa_load_verify_metadata::nm 
Value              Size               Type  Bind  Other Shndx    Name
0xfffffffffbfc11f0|0x0000000000000004|OBJT |GLOB |0x0  |6       |spa_load_verify_metadata
```

More information can be found here: [Oracle Solaris Modular Debugger Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61056/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer!